# Ruby On rails validations

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails.

I Have create a simple rails page which accepts bookid, title and publisher

rails generate scaffold book bookid:string title:string publisher:string

I have written a new search.html.erb and a defination to it which search for books by title.

Now my Question is how do i give a custom message if that book details doesn't exist in database.

Ex : I gave book name as rails it doesn't have any entry in my database

it should give message **No Such Books**

Comment: Please add more information about your current situation: controller, view. Without it it's hard to provide you complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
# controller
def search
  @books = Book.where('title ilike ?', "%#{params[:title]}%")
end

# view
<% if @books.present? %>
  Some code with your books
<% else %>
  No such books
<% end %>
```

Here you substitute given *title* param into query and assign found books to *@books*. Then you use this variable in your views.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear where you want to display it but something like this...

In your controller:

```
@book = Books.find(params[:book_id])
if @book
  @msg = "Book found"
else
  @msg = "No Such Books"
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= @msg =>
```